# Retrofit: on failure status code return null pointer.

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am using Retrofit for my backend communication:
If the status code is not 200 then the callback call failure method.
But I want to get the status code inside the failure method for further code conditioning

```
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {

                Logger.e("ERROR Status:", retrofitError.getResponse().getStatus() + "");

            }
        }
```

But the above code always give a null pointer exception.
How do i get the status code of my header on failure.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug. Add OkHttp's latest version to your dependencies.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
```

Comment: will adding this version help???  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-tests:1.5.1'

Comment: that looks like test version?